# Difference between the Regex expressions in dotnet

Tags: c#, regex

what is the difference between the two regex

```
new Regex(@"(([[[{""]))", RegexOptions.Compiled)
```

and

```
new Regex(@"(^[[[{""])", RegexOptions.Compiled)
```

I've used the both regex but can't find the difference. it's almost match similar things.

Comment: `^` is start of string

Comment: @vks In this usage. It can also be used to denote an exclusionary character set, if it's inside of a character set.

Comment: @vks Hence why I said "in this usage".

Comment: Do these regexes even compile? You have unescaped quotes in it.

Comment: thanks, i know that indicates the start of string, i'm using regex to server side validation. but the value of this returns false `new Regex(@"(^[[[{""])", RegexOptions.Compiled).IsMatch("new (\"val\",\"5\")")` and the value of `new Regex(@"(([[[{""]))", RegexOptions.Compiled).IsMatch("new (\"val\",\"5\")")` returns true, so can anyone tell me the difference of this, why the first one doesn't matches the string

Comment: @melwil No he doesn't  ;)

Comment: If you know that it means start of string, then you already have the answer as to why both don't work. Inspecting your target string visually, where is the substring you are trying to match?

Comment: Also, don't forget that `()` denotes a capture group unless you escape the parentheses.

Comment: sorry, i'm not familiar with regex. now only trying to learn.the basics only easy to me, but in that i'm not find the difference between the regex. also i wanna to be use it for the validate model. so can you explain it briefly

Comment: Learn here https://regex101.com/ .......... the explanations are on the right side........ if you want only `C#` use http://regexstorm.net/

Comment: On a side note, you're misusing the `Compiled` option.  It *can* make regexes more efficient, but it comes with a non-trivial front end cost.  With a simple regex like this one, the additional overhead easily cancels out the benefit of improved efficiency.  `RegexOptions.Compiled` is something you should use only when you *know* you need it.  [[1](http://allben.net/post.aspx?id=41984cfd-90a9-4a94-b6e7-1dc1c3c3ac76)] [[2](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/regular-expressions-advanced/)]

Answer (score 1):

The regex patterns are not well written because

1. There are duplicate characters in character classes (thus redundant)
2. The first regex contains duplicate capture group on the whole pattern.

The first regex - `(([[[{""]))` - matches 1 character, either a `[`, a `{`, or a `"`, and captures it into Group 1 and Group 2. See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=((%5b%5b%5b%7b%22%22%5d))&i=%5b%5b%5b%22%22%7b). It is equal to

```
[[{"]
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5B%7B%22%5D&i=%5B%5B%5B%22%22%7B)

The second regex - `(^[[[{""])` - only matches the same characters as the pattern above, but *at the beginning of a string* (if `RegexOptions.Multiline` is not set), *or the beginning of a line* (if that option is set). See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5E%5B%5B%5B%7B%22%22%5D)&i=%5B%5B%5B%22%22%7B). It is equal to

```
^[[{"]
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B%5B%7B%22%5D&i=%5B%5B%5B%22%22%7B)

You will access the matched characters using `Regex.Match(s).Value`.

[*More about anchors*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Aslo see [*Caret ^: Beginning of String (or Line)*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#caret)